# How to dynamically create separate entry points depending on the each folder?

Tags: webpack

I wanna to include all my translations per each folder into separate bundle. How i can rewrite this into once require?

```
switch(locale){
  case 'en':
    require.ensure([], require => {
      context = require.context('../../locales/en/', true, /\.yml$/);
      this.loadTranslate(context);
    });
    break;
  case 'ru':
    require.ensure([], require => {
      context = require.context('../../locales/ru/', true, /\.yml$/);
      this.loadTranslate(context);
    });
    break;
}
```